# java.lang.ClassCastException: JedisConnectionFactory cannot be cast to ConnectionFactory

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm not sure why Method "connectionFactory" is returning an instance of JedisConnecionFactory, should it not be  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory?

The following exception on line "new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory())" (see code below)

```
Feb 23, 2015 11:50:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
r:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.queue.MessageQueueSender]: Factory method 'messageQueueSender' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/config/MessageQueueConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: Factory method 'rabbitTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/config/MessageQueueConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: Factory method 'rabbitTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:322) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.rabbitTemplate(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig.messageQueueSender(MessageQueueConfig.java:61) ~[MessageQueueConfig.class:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.CGLIB$messageQueueSender$1(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99208f13.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.messageQueueSender(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate]: Factory method 'rabbitTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.connectionFactory(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig.rabbitTemplate(MessageQueueConfig.java:75) ~[MessageQueueConfig.class:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.CGLIB$rabbitTemplate$2(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99208f13.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  at com.config.MessageQueueConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68caa0b1.rabbitTemplate(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
  ... 46 common frames omitted
```

@Configuation Class

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"..."})
public class MessageQueueConfig {
    ..
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(url);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("message.queue");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@ComponentScan` must be finding another configuration file with a redis connection factory bean with the same name which is overriding this one.

You can use DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; it emits copious logs when resolving beans.

Alternatively, simply change your bean definition to use a different bean name: `rabbitConnectionFactory()`